# Get the value of print statement of sql server in vb.net by using oledb

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, ado.net

I am trying to create an query analyzer and executor.

I wonder that how to get the output message of an transact-sql statement like 'PRINT'

```
declare @msg varchar(100)

set @msg =  select [column] from [table name] where [column] = [condition]

if @msg = 'SOMEVALUE'
 begin
   print 'This is first statement'
 end
else
 begin
  print 'This is second statement'
 end
```

can you please help me to get the value of print statement of above code in vb.net

Thanks in advance

Comment: For future reference, PRINT is not a good way to return data back to the caller.  A result set or OUTPUT parameter is more standard.

Comment: I aware that PRINT ins not a good way to return data back to the caller , but I am creating the the query analyzer for general user so i don't want to bound them to use only select to see the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w.aspx):

> You can retrieve warnings and informational messages from a SQL Server
>   data source using the InfoMessage event of the SqlConnection object.

The informational messages that is being referred here includes the value being returned by **print** command.

Update:

```
AddHandler myConnection.InfoMessage, New SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(AddressOf OnInfoMessage)

Private Sub OnInfoMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventArgs)
        mySB.AppendLine(e.Message)
End Sub
```

Where myConnection is you SQL connection and mySB is your String Builder.

e.Message has the value of `print`.

Comment: It worked perfectly, i just change the "SqlInfoMessageEventHandler" to "OleDbInfoMessageEventHandler" . Thanks

Comment: Using this only gives the message at the end of the process. Is there any way to get the output message dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I still suggest using SELECT. No output parameters needed

```
if @msg = 'SOMEVALUE'
 begin
   select 'This is first statement'
 end
else
 begin
     select 'This is second statement'
 end
```

*This* you can get in your VB.NET code via simple [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) (Or its SqlClient equivalent if you decide not to use OleDB for SQL Server).

Comment: I know very well that the value of select statement can be retrieve very easily via ExecuteScalar, but my requirement is to get the value of print statement, above answer of MSDN is work perfectly.